# Querydsl list contains an object of a certain class

Tags: java, querydsl

I have the following class structure:

```
public class Main{
   List<A> listOfA;
}

public abstract class A{}

public class B extends A{}

public class C extends A{}
```

Is it possible to do the following query somehow (the code below is not working):

```
QMain.main.listOfA.contains(QB.b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work

```
QMain.main.listOfA.any().instanceOf(B.class)
```

Comment: hi thank you for your answer its working perfectly. How ever since A is an abstract class, as i read earlier that i have to refer to my B class like so: new QB("A"). Unfortunately this works but it keeps breaking my query since it trying to reach an attribute in my A class whats only exists in my B class. It produces the following query: select 1 from A... instead of my B class.